# How to display a text inside a tag if a value passed from controller is true using blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to disable input if the value transferred from the controller is false. I read the [blade template documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade) for Laravel, but couldn't find any useful resource.

I tried the following code, but it yields an error.

```
<input type="text" name="url" style="height:36px;"   value="http://theurl.in/{{$link_data->hash}}" @if $isEditable {{ 'enabled' }} @endif /> <br/>
```

The exact code part is,

```
@if $isEditable {{ 'enabled' }} @endif
```

[image]

If you can provide any suggestion, it would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the purpose of  the 'enabled' string is but you don't need it. HTML inputs are enabled by default. What you need is a simple ternary that prints `disabled="disabled"`.

```
{{ !$isEnabled ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a syntax error. If you check the blade templating documentation, [if conditions need to be in parenthesis](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#if-statements), so the solution should be like this:

```
@if ($isEditable) {{ 'enabled' }} @endif
```

I also agree with Ohgodwhy's answer, HTML inputs are enabled by default, so you should just put:

```
@if (!$isEditable) {{ 'disabled=disabled' }} @endif
```